# ¿Como crear un proyecto demo para pluggins en nativescript?

Tags: plugin, nativescript

Recientemente me he estado metiendo a aprender nativescript para la creación de pluggins pero para mi primer ejercicio en el curso al usar ***tns plugin create example*** no me sale esta estructura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y siempre me marca este error al momento de crear el proyecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Dejándome con esta estructura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Alguien me podría decir si ha habido cambios en la elaboración de proyectos nativescript? ¿Cómo puedo crear un proyecto demo para el mismo?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Y que estructura te sale?

Comment: La misma pero sin las carpetas demo y demo-angular, de echo la consola me marca error precisamente por que no se generan esas dos carpetas.

Comment: Bueno.. hay un par de errores al crear no.. habria que empezar por ahi....